# Set up a language by default on HTML5 alerts

Tags: javascript, html

I know that there is a way to set up this the way I like, once you put the required attribute, you know that if the input isn't filled out, then a message will come up, If er the Browser is in Spanish, the HTML5 error message will be in Spanish, or if the Browser is in English, then the error will be in English.

My question: how can I do to set up the language of those messages in Spanish by default?

I am aware of the setCustomValidity of JavaScript, but I also checked this before http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp but anyways applying the `lang="es"` it doesn't work.

Now my simple form:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" pattern="\d{1,15}" required />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```